# How to exclude characters from a print if value is not greater than 0 or blank

Tags: python, copy, pysimplegui

I'm working on a program with PySimpleGui that will copy a finished and refined result list to my clipboard when I press the copy button. So far, it's looking good, but when I copy it, I don't want to include the characters G(Goal), A(Assist) and O.G(Own Goal) if the value is not greater than 0 (If the boxes in the program is blank in other words). Right now, when you run this code under, and you Copy it, you will get [G] [A] [O.G] besides the TEAM1 positions GK, CDM, MID and ST. I haven't yet done TEAM2. Will finish it when I have figured this out.

So what I want from this, is some tips on what I should do, to not include these characters. I'm figuring I need to probably make some definitions with some if and else statements, but it might be a little complicated, considering I only am 3-4 months into Python.

Can someone help me?

[Picture of the program][1]

````
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyperclip

SYMBOL_UP = '▶'
SYMBOL_DOWN = '❌'

sg.theme_background_color('#1e1e1e')
sg.theme_text_color("#FAFFFF")
sg.theme_input_background_color("#FAFFFF")
sg.theme_button_color("#494949")
sg.theme_text_element_background_color("#1e1e1e")
sg.theme_element_background_color("#1e1e1e")

def collapse(layout, key):
    return sg.pin(sg.Column(layout, key=key))

section1 =[
    [sg.Multiline(key="home_subs", size=(20,3))]
    ]

section2 =[
    [sg.Multiline(key="away_subs", size=(20, 3))]
]

section3 =[
    [sg.Text("EXTRA")]
]

layout = [
    [sg.Text("STATCOUNTER by ClayAces v.1")],
    [sg.Text("------------------")],
    # HOME TEAM
    [sg.Text("HOME TEAM", text_color='#fce784'), sg.Combo(["TEAM1", "TEAM2", "TEAM3","TEAM4","TEAM5","TEAM6"],
        default_value="TEAM1", key="TEAM_1", size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key="TEAM1_Score", size=(3,1))],
    [sg.Text("GK:"), sg.InputText(key="HomeGK", size=(14,1)), sg.Text("G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1),
        key="homegk_g"), sg.Text("A:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1), key="homegk_a"), sg.Text("O.G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1), key="homegk_og")],
    [sg.Text("CDM:"), sg.InputText(key="HomeCDM", size=(14,1)), sg.Text("G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1),
        key="homecdm_g"), sg.Text("A:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1), key="homecdm_a"), sg.Text("O.G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1), key="homecdm_og")],
    [sg.Text("MID:"), sg.InputText(key="HomeMID", size=(14,1)), sg.Text("G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1),
        key="homemid_g"), sg.Text("A:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1), key="homemid_a"), sg.Text("O.G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1), key="homemid_og")],
    [sg.Text("ST:"), sg.InputText(key="HomeST", size=(14,1)), sg.Text("G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1),
        key="homest_g"), sg.Text("A:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1), key="homest_a"), sg.Text("O.G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2,1), key="homest_og")],
    #  SECTION 1
    [sg.T(SYMBOL_DOWN, enable_events=True, k='-OPEN SEC1-', text_color='#fce784'),
     sg.T('Home subs', enable_events=True, text_color='#fce784', k='-OPEN SEC1-TEXT')],
    [collapse(section1, '-SEC1-')],
    # AWAY TEAM
    [sg.Text("AWAY TEAM", text_color='#fce784'), sg.Combo(["TEAM1", "TEAM2", "TEAM3","TEAM4","TEAM5","TEAM6"],
        default_value="TEAM2", key="TEAM_2", size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key="TEAM2_Score", size=(3,1))],
    [sg.Text("GK:"), sg.InputText(key="AwayGK", size=(14, 1)), sg.Text("G:"),
     sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaygk_g"), sg.Text("A:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaygk_a"),
     sg.Text("O.G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaygk_og")],
    [sg.Text("CDM:"), sg.InputText(key="AwayCDM", size=(14, 1)), sg.Text("G:"),
     sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaycdm_g"), sg.Text("A:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaycdm_a"),
     sg.Text("O.G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaycdm_og")],
    [sg.Text("MID:"), sg.InputText(key="AwayMID", size=(14, 1)), sg.Text("G:"),
     sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaymid_g"), sg.Text("A:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaymid_a"),
     sg.Text("O.G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awaymid_og")],
    [sg.Text("ST:"), sg.InputText(key="AwayST", size=(14, 1)), sg.Text("G:"),
     sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awayst_g"), sg.Text("A:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awayst_a"),
     sg.Text("O.G:"), sg.InputText("", size=(2, 1), key="Awayst_og")],
    #  SECTION 2
    [sg.T(SYMBOL_DOWN, enable_events=True, k='-OPEN SEC2-', text_color='#fce784'),
     sg.T('Away subs', enable_events=True, text_color='#fce784', k='-OPEN SEC2-TEXT')],
    [collapse(section2, '-SEC2-')],
    # RESULTS
    [sg.Button("COPY RESULTS", key="Copy")],
    #  SECTION 3
    [sg.T(SYMBOL_DOWN, enable_events=True, k='-OPEN SEC3-', text_color='#fce784'),
     sg.T('Extras', enable_events=True, text_color='#fce784', k='-OPEN SEC3-TEXT')],
    [collapse(section3, '-SEC3-')],
]
window = sg.Window("STATCOUNTER v.1", layout, font="Calibri, 11", element_padding=(3, 3),element_justification='r')

opened1, opened2, opened3 = True, True, True

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if event.startswith('-OPEN SEC1-'):
        opened1 = not opened1
        window['-OPEN SEC1-'].update(SYMBOL_DOWN if opened1 else SYMBOL_UP)
        window['-SEC1-'].update(visible=opened1)

    if event.startswith('-OPEN SEC2-'):
            opened2 = not opened2
            window['-OPEN SEC2-'].update(SYMBOL_DOWN if opened2 else SYMBOL_UP)
            window['-SEC2-'].update(visible=opened2)

    if event.startswith('-OPEN SEC3-'):
            opened3 = not opened3
            window['-OPEN SEC3-'].update(SYMBOL_DOWN if opened3 else SYMBOL_UP)
            window['-SEC3-'].update(visible=opened3)

    if event == "Copy":
        pyperclip.copy(f"""
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
{'TEAM1'} {values['TEAM1_Score']}-{values['TEAM2_Score']} {'TEAM2'}

{'TEAM1'}

GK: {values['HomeGK']} [{values['homegk_g']}]G [{values['homegk_a']}A] [{values['homegk_og']}O.G]
CDM: {values['HomeCDM']} [{values['homecdm_g']}G] [{values['homecdm_a']}A] [{values['homecdm_og']}O.G]
MID: {values['HomeMID']} [{values['homemid_g']}G] [{values['homemid_a']}A] [{values['homemid_og']}O.G]
ST:{values['HomeST']} [{values['homest_g']}G] [{values['homest_a']}A] [{values['homest_og']}O.G]

SUBS:
{values['home_subs']}

{'TEAM2'}

GK: {values['AwayGK']}
CDM: {values['AwayCDM']}
MID: {values['AwayMID']}
ST: {values['AwayST']}

SUBS:
{values['away_subs']}
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
""") ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDpKB.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check the user inputs before copying them.

First you need to retrieve the value. For example:

```
input_data = values['homegk_g']
```

Then you need to check its value, If it is equal to an empty string or not (which means the user has entered something or not) as below:

```
if input_data != "":
    # rest of the script
```

The other way of checking that the user has entered some data is by comparing the `len()` of `InputText` to `0` as below:

```
if len(input_data) > 0:
    # rest of the script
```

Now if I want to show a sample of your script with user input checking it will be like this:

```
if event == "Copy":

    # copy this for other desired fields. 
    input_data_hm_gk_g = values['homegk_g']
    input_data_hm_gk_a = values['homegk_a']
    input_data_hm_gk_og = values['homegk_og']
    if len(input_data_hm_gk) > 0 and len(input_data_hm_gk_a) > 0 and 
                                        len(input_data_hm_gk_og) > 0:


        pyperclip.copy(f"""
        =-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        {'TEAM1'} {values['TEAM1_Score']}-{values['TEAM2_Score']} {'TEAM2'}

        {'TEAM1'}

        GK: {values['HomeGK']} [{values['homegk_g']}]G [{values['homegk_a']}A] 
        [{values['homegk_og']}O.G]
        CDM: {values['HomeCDM']} [{values['homecdm_g']}G] 
        [{values['homecdm_a']}A] 
        [{values['homecdm_og']}O.G]
        MID: {values['HomeMID']} [{values['homemid_g']}G] 
        [{values['homemid_a']}A] 
        [{values['homemid_og']}O.G]
        ST:{values['HomeST']} [{values['homest_g']}G] [{values['homest_a']}A] 
        [{values['homest_og']}O.G]

        SUBS:
        {values['home_subs']}

        {'TEAM2'}

        GK: {values['AwayGK']}
        CDM: {values['AwayCDM']}
        MID: {values['AwayMID']}
        ST: {values['AwayST']}

        SUBS:
        {values['away_subs']}
        =-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
        """)
```

You have so many input fields to check so I recommend you to code an individual function that checks if all input fields have been filled or not. You can simply do this by iterating on `values` and those condition checks I have told you above.

Answer (score 0):

(im new to python so please dislike if not helpful)
why don't you use '>'

'>' means that the value on the left is higher than the one on the right.

example

```
new_list = [] 
for item in list:
  if item > 0:
    new_list.append(item)
```